# How to add 3 int from score to a total score in android studio

Tags: java, android, calculation

I am trying to build a score card from different levels of play. In android studio

I tried by adding the 3 int's togther, i also tried to make a double out of it. But i can't get the total. I do get for each level the score

```
public class ScoresActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv_total_Score, tvPersonalBest_Begin, tvPersonalBest_Normal, tvPersonalBest_Advance;
    Button btnReturn;

    int totalscore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        int scoreSPBG = pref.getInt("scoreSPBG", 0);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        int scoreSP = prefs.getInt("scoreSP", 0);
        SharedPreferences prefz = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        int scoreSPAD = prefz.getInt("scoreSPAD", 0);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editors = prefs.edit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorz = prefs.edit();
        editorz.putInt("scoreSAD", scoreSPAD);
        editor.putInt("scoreSPBG", scoreSPBG);
        editors.putInt("scoreSp", scoreSP);
        editors.apply();
        editorz.apply();
        editor.apply();



        tv_total_Score = findViewById(R.id.tv_total_Score);
        tvPersonalBest_Begin = findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalBest_Begin);
        tvPersonalBest_Normal = findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalBest_Normal);
        tvPersonalBest_Advance = findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalBest_Advance);

        btnReturn =findViewById(R.id.btn_return);

        Double n1 = Double.valueOf(tvPersonalBest_Begin.getText().toString());
        double n2 =Double.valueOf(tvPersonalBest_Normal.getText().toString());
       double n3 =Double.valueOf(tvPersonalBest_Advance.getText().toString());        

       double result = n1+n2+n3;
       tv_total_Score.setText("" + result);

         totalscore = scoreSPBG + scoreSP + scoreSPAD;
         tv_total_Score.setText("" + totalscore);


        tvPersonalBest_Begin.setText("" + scoreSPBG);
        tvPersonalBest_Normal.setText("" + scoreSP);
        tvPersonalBest_Advance.setText("" + scoreSPAD);

        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new  Intent(ScoresActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(returnIntent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I tried with double and i tried with int to get a calculation. But i cant get the total amount of my 3 levels.

Comment: what is actual output, and what is the expected?

Comment: Why do you handle three separate instances of the same `SharedPreferences` and three instances of `Editor`?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the output should be the sum of the 3 int.

Comment: @QBrute I am a newby at programming. I tried different things i see on the net. And i also tried this. I am not getting an error in android studio so i thought i would be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a typo at:

```
editorz.putInt("scoreSAD", scoreSPAD);
```

should be:

```
editorz.putInt("scoreSPAD", scoreSPAD);
```

To avoid this kind of errors in the future consider to use constants for preference keys.

Second, you are accessing preferences to get stored values and stores them again inmediatelly without having changed them. Note you show result's variable value first but in next line you update it with the sum of preferences values. Therefore you'll always have zeros

Third, you are storing them in preferences as int, but you get them as double from view, use getDouble and putDouble methods if you expect them to have decimals.

Fourth, Although I guess you are calling ScoresActivity recursivelly just to debug, consider using extras to pass arguments to an activity instead of using preferences (if you are not aiming to persist them)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Changing my typo and do a change in code calculated the 3 values. totalscore = scoreSPBG + scoreSPAD + scoreSP;  I am a newby without much knowledge so i do my best trying to figure out things.

Comment: You are welcome, just one more thing, consider using just one SharedPreferences variable. You can then use any number of putWhatever() methods with just one use of edit() and apply() methods. Much more clean and readable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to do a good tutorial about SharedPreference. The official one is well done: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#java)
In your case, pref, prefs and prefz are exactly the same and so you don't need to create 3 Editors. Also, why retrieving scores in preferences to inject them just after.
So maybe you did not put the score in sharedpreference well, and retrieve always 0. That's why tv_total_Score display 0.

Also, no need to use Double if you have only int.
And name your variables with the camel case convention, avoid underline.